# Translation of 'verbose'

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

I'm a software developer and  I've seen thousands of times the word "verbose" in different tutorials, frameworks, etc. I wonder, which would be the correct translation of the word "verbose" in Spanish?

I tried translating it with *Google Translate* and I got "verboso" .. I don't even know the meaning of that word in Spanish.

Maybe "verboso" is the correct spanish translation, but is there any other word more known or used? (never heard of it, at least in Latin America).

For instance, in this [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) of the Django documentation, we have an example of how "verbose" is used:

> Each field type [...] takes an optional first positional argument -- a **verbose** name. If the **verbose** name isn't given, Django will automatically create it using the field's attribute name, converting underscores to spaces.

Comment: What is "verbose" used to refer to?

Comment: "Verbose" in regular English means someone or something that is very (maybe excessively) detailed in describing things. In a software development context, it generally describes an option for how detailed the output of a program should be (there is often a `--verbose` option or a "verbosity" setting).

Comment: @Alenanno I have added a paragraph to see the word "verbose" within a context.

Comment: @jrdioko yes, that's also the concept I have from "verbose" in the software development context. So, which do you think would be the most accurate translation?

Comment: *Verbose* would translate to *verboso*, but why do you need the exact translation? Are you translating some documentation? Or you just want to know what it means?

Comment: @Eduardo very good question, I did know what "verbose" meant. It was a mix of curiosity to know the exact translation of the word and a project I have to translate some documentation.

Answer (score 8):

In the software development context, I think `verboso` is the more appropriate way of translating `verbose`; however, when related to a person other alternatives are:

- Locuaz (Closer meaning to verbose, not negative context)
- Hablador (Could mean that either talks too much or he/she is a gossiper. Context determines the meaning)
- Parlanchín (Talks too much)
- Lenguaraz (Talks too much)

Admittedly, `verboso` is not often used in the spoken language but it wouldn't be incorrect to tell someone something like:

> Tú eres muy verbosa, al grano, por favor.

Instead, one would say:

> Tú eres muy locuaz, al grano, por favor. (formal)
>
> Tú te extiendes mucho, al grano, por favor. (a bit more informal)

Answer (score 5):

Se suele aplicar *verbose* a los métodos de presentación donde se relaciona mayor información y más detallada que en un informe normal.
En este caso podríamos traducirlo como **detallado** o **pormenorizado**.

Comment: +1.  Linguee.com gave me: "User can also use so called verbose mode. | *El usuario también puede usar el denominado modo detallado.*"  Which sounds very good to me.

Comment: No reo que podamos decir de los lenguajes tipo C que lo sean. Un dump (volcado de memoria) un log o cualquier otro registro de procesos si podemos decir que son detallados. Aunque también podemos sacar información resumida, generalmente como una opción a parte.

Answer (score 3):

While *verboso* is correct, the one I've seen used more frequently is **verborrágico**, which essentially means *very verbose*.

Comment: You reminded me of **verborrea**: "La verborrea de Chávez es insufrible, el Rey lo mandó callar".

Answer (score 2):

*Verboso* is a good translation. *Prolijo* also works, especially if you are referring to written texts.

In the particular case of "verbose names" in programming, I'd probably use *nombres largos* as a free translation.

Comment: Be aware that "prolijo" has another meaning (tidy, neat), which is prevalent is some regions (as Argentina)

Comment: @leonbloy: Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

"Verboso" appears to be a "faithful translation of "verbose." Both mean "wordy," that is, using too many words to describe/discuss something.